# SSD does not show up in server without RAID

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, hardware-raid

I have a server Supermicro SuperServer 6017R-72RFTP with the motherboard X9DRW-7TPF. I have a 1TB Samsung SSD. The SSD shows up when the server boots and in the BIOS, but when I go to install an OS it says there are no drives.

My server admin set up RAID 0 which showed it up as a virtual device, but I didn't ask him to do that and I do not want any RAID. There is no point of RAID 0 on a single drive, and worse, it runs higher risk of catastrophic data loss.

What can be the cause of this and how can I get the hard drive to show so I can install CentOS?

the hard drive shows up on boot (also checked it in the BIOS) 
(screenshot from before adding the RAID 0):
[image: screenshot of bootup screen]

but no hard drive shows in centos for install:
[image: screenshot of centos, no hdd]

UPDATE

As mentioned, The drive shows when put in RAID 0, but I don't want any RAID. When in RAID 0 it shows on the boot screen above as 1 Virtual Drive instead of 0 Virtual Drives. Then in CentOS it shows this:
[image: drive in RAID 0]

Although it shows on RAID 0, I don't want any RAID at all.

What can be the cause of this and how can I get the hard drive to show so I can install CentOS?

Comment: The model you have is the motherboard but what server is it? You need to delete the RAID 0 from where it was configured.

Comment: @NasirRiley The server is Supermicro Model: SuperServer 6017R-72RFTP

Answer (score 1):

You probably saw an artifact of how the controller sees its disks: You could say that a single drive is a 1-drive RAID0: Every "stripe" gets written to the same disk. In other words you probably haven't got a higher risk of catastrophic hardware failure than you'd expect with any controller+single disk combination.

Regarding the CentOS installer not seeing the drive:

- Make sure the controller software recognizes and presents a virtual drive (which is your "RAID0").
- Make sure your RAID controller is supported by the operating system you're trying to install.

Comment: CentOS... I'd bet on the problem #2.

Comment: @MikaelH The disk shows actually when it is set up as a virtual disk under RAID 0. My question was about getting it to work without any RAID at all.

Comment: From the product page of the motherboard: "8x SAS2 ports via Broadcom 2208, support HW RAID 0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 50, 60". Of those choices, RAID0 on a single disk sounds like your most viable choice if you want the possible benefits of the RAID/SAS controller in terms of cache, etc. Otherwise the mainboard also is equipped with regular SATA ports which should behave more like you expect.

Comment: As I said I do not want any RAID

Comment: Yes, I saw @shodanshok gave you a good answer in another thread: If it's available (which it isn't on some controllers), pass-through is what you should choose. Otherwise, as I wrote earlier, the motherboard has regular SATA ports, which won't pass through the RAID controller. I still claim, though, that with a single disk, the overall risk of using RAID0 isn't noticeably larger, because the most probable result of a failure will be a need to restore from backups in any case.